# Как сделать переключение между несколькими адресами на Google maps по нажатию одной кнопки в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api, google-maps

На карте имеется плашка с текущим адресом и синяя кнопка со стрелкой вперед, при нажатии на которую должны меняться нужные адреса на карте. Если есть подобное в Яндекс-картах, и это сойдет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что попробовали вы и у вас не получилось?

Comment: Нет. Я даже не знаю с чего и как начать. Внешний вид по средствам HTML и CSS я осуществил в этом нет проблем. Но как осуществить данный функционал. Что использовать? JS? может плагины какие? js я знаю поверхностно и если разъяснить "что куда" думаю справлюсь.

Comment: достаточно почитать Google Maps Api(JS), там все детально описано и пошагово, в Вашем случае конкртено нужен click Listener и вызов bounds

Comment: Ахах, видел этот проект пару дней назад на fl.ru Ну норм, как обычно заказчик выбрал исполнителя, который даже не знает, что с этим делать)) Давай, дерзай

Comment: @eugene_v этого проекта нет на fl.ru Чел будь благоразумным, подскажи если ты знаешь что с этим делать, а так то степ на каждого найдется ))) не суди строго, но начинающим ведь когда то нужно начинать.